# SQL сбор данных по префиксам в других базах

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите как правильно сформировать запрос 
если в одной базе у меня хранятся префиксы городов и по этим префиксам нужно подключиться к другим базам и там выбрать нужные данные с таблиц 
к примеру есть база

`public` - общая база где можно найти список городов

```
select id, prefix 
      from public.city
      where active = 1
```

здесь мы получаем массив с префиксами городов к примеру london, kiev

и есть базы городов

```
base_london
base_kiev
```

как мне добраться к таблицам user каждого города при условии что у меня уже есть префиксы городов ?

```
    select *
    from (select  prefix 
          from public.city
          where active = 1) as pc
   ....... ???
```

БД 
MySql 5.6

и у всех баз есть таблица user
base_london.user или base_kiev.user

хотелось бы одним запросом вытянуть всех юзеров с разбивкой по городам

Comment: *к примеру есть база* Это - запрос. С лишним непонятно откуда приблудившимся словом "public".

Comment: public - общая база где можно найти список городов

Comment: *как мне добраться к таблицам user каждого города при условии что у меня уже есть префиксы городов* Во-первых, это однозначно динамический SQL. Во-вторых, указывайте ТОЧНО используемую СУБД, включая её версию.

Comment: *public - общая база где можно найти список городов* Пожалуйста, не используйте придуманную Вами терминологию, придерживайтесь общепринятой. И не смешивайте в одной конструкции элементы синтаксисов нескольких систем/языков.

Comment: база данных   MySql 5.6

Comment: @Akina чего вас зацепило это `public`, просто база так называется у него, имя БД т.е. зы: по сабжу не префиксы а суффиксы.

Comment: *как правильно сформировать запрос* Вопрос - где именно Вы желаете "формировать запрос"? Вариант 1 - на стороне MySQL, обращаетесь к хранимой процедуре и получаете набор пользователей в форме одного либо нескольких рекордсетов. Вариант 2 - на стороне PHP, одним запросом получаете список городов, формируете по нему второй запрос (или набор запросов), и по ним получаете списки пользователей.

Comment: @teran *чего вас зацепило это public* Автор публикует фрагмент, форматированный как код, но синтаксически неверный. И понимать, где именно он допустил косяк, и какого рода... по-хорошему он и должен был исправлять.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не получится в конструкции `from` указать результат подзапроса. Первым запросов вы извлекасаете перечень нужных префиксов, вторым уже непосредственные данные.

Если работаете только с одним городом, то префикс (*вообще префикс это в начале слова, а суффикс в конце, так что `london` в `base_london` это суффикс*) в переменную, и ее в запрос. Если префиксов несколько, то объединяете запросы через `UNION`

```
 $row = $c->execute("select ... from `public.city` where .... limit 1")
          ->fetch('assoc');
 $dbname = "base_" . $row['prefix'];

 $users = $c->execute("select ... from `$dbname`.users where ....")
            ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

либо

```
 $cities = $c->execute("select ... from `public.city` where ... ")
             ->fetchAll('assoc');

 $queries = [];
 $prefixes = array_column($cities, 'prefix');
 foreach($prefixes as $p){
      $dbname = "base_$p";
      $queries[] = "SELECT ...
                            , '$p' as city  
                    FROM `$dbname`.users 
                    WHERE ....";
 } 
 $sql = implode("\nUNION\n", $queries);

 $users = $c->execute($sql)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

*зы: код условный*

Comment: а с помощью SQL запроса реализация возможна  ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник эту же логику вы вполне можете реализовать в хранимой процедуре

Comment: с помощью  mySql  вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: да, с помощью mysql